# How to make the /checkout/cart page load with HTTPS?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, https

My checkout and user pages are loading with HTTPS correctly. For some reason the cart page isn't (**/checkout/cart**).

Magento is configured to use secure URLs both in the frontend and the backend.

If I manually write the cart's URL with HTTPS it loads correctly, with the green padlock.  I'd like the cart page to **always load https** by default.

Is there any way to do this?

*Running Magento 1.9.2*

Note: I don't want all pages in the website to load securely

Answer (score 1):

Edit app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/config.xml, find this:

```
<frontend>
<secure_url>
```

And add this line immediately below:

```
<checkout_cart>/checkout/cart</checkout_cart>
```

So that it looks like this:

```
<frontend>
   <secure_url>
      <checkout_cart>/checkout/cart</checkout_cart>
      <checkout_onepage>/checkout/onepage</checkout_onepage>
      <checkout_multishipping>/checkout/multishipping</checkout_multishipping>
</secure_url>
```

**Source: Google**