# How can I modify my cart form page to complete https

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, shopping, ssl-certificate

I am working on my client's website https://gerrykeane.ie/ and when I add a product to the cart I get promoted a warning  message that the form page is not secure. I have updated the security certificates to my domains , but that page that is throwing error is https://gerrykeane.ie/checkout/cart/. There is a link being used in the form redirection that is not secured as I am trying to find a way to edit that to https (http://gerrykeane.ie/checkout/cart/updatePost/)

Any help will be welcome.

Thanks
Nipun

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that your M2 shop(s) is(are) setup for full HTTPS.

Look at M2 configurations for all scopes:
1/ Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Base URLs

- verify all links are in HTTPS
  2/ Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Base URLs (Secure):
- Verify all links are in HTTPS
- Use Secure URLs on Storefront: Yes
- Use Secure URLs in Admin: Yes

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for coming back.  All the links in base URL are already HTTPS. I have left the Unsecure  base url to http. Any other thing that you can suggest ? I saw another thread (very old one) with similar issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141704/how-to-make-the-checkout-cart-page-load-with-https, but as I am not techy, I cannot find a place to fix that as suggested. Do you know where should I add that line of code?

Comment: He is using Magento 1

Comment: I suggest to keep HTTPS everywhere, you don't need HTTP as it's not secure for your visitors / customers. Browers will also show your site is unsecure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the search of your IDE to search in the files for "product_addtocart_form". This is the ID of the  that has the http link. Now you should look for the function inside of the "action" attribute. That is the function generating the http link. It usually should look like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>
```

But it is also possible that the link is being generated inside of the block class.
The _secure parameter is what makes the link use HTTPS when it is enabled on your Magento configuration.